# How can I track down what is causing my mouse to hang?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, performance-tuning

I am trying to eliminate a random (and quite frustrating) behavior.  At seemingly random intervals my mouse (a corded Razor Mamba) doesn't respond.  I have stripped out just about every imaginable background task and replaced every wireless device with a corded device.  I have also had the Task Manager Performance tab open to see if there was some associated spike in something (RAM, CPU, or I/O), but all remain relatively flat.  I have disabled the Realtek HD Audio Manager (referenced in one article as a possible culprit in mouse hanging), but still, the problem persists.  The computer is very capable (i7 Skylake X, 32 GB of RAM and a Samsung SSD 950 PRO NVMe drive [image: task manager]

Any ideas where I can turn to next?

Comment: I think its your CPU. Sometimes the interrupt from your mouse is ignored by your CPU. https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/474511-stuttering-issues-with-new-skylake-build-help/

Comment: Check `Device Manager` and make sure devices are not disappearing (Specifically your Mouse)

I would also recommend you look into updating your drivers, specifically your USB Controller or Chipset.

Comment: @CheesusCrust I built this PC less than a month ago and I started with a clean copy of Windows 10 Pro, and everything I could get from here https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/TUF-X299-MARK-2/HelpDesk_Download/ so I believe the drivers are updated.  I double check the device manager and nothing is flagged as missing a driver, however after taking that screenshot I am now trying to reproduce the mouse hang bug with Elgato Sound Capture and IAStoreIcon disabled (I don't have any SATA drives in this computer so I don't need to monitor them)

Comment: My motherboard does have a PS/2 port, so I can try that, however disabled even more software hasn't removed the "random" lag

Comment: The lag doesnt seem to be related to whats running and your resources.  (As you have plenty)  My first assumption would be that it is driver related.  Try reinstalling the drivers that may affect the mouse.  Like the ones I mentioned previously.  Razor is also known to have special drivers for their hardware, so I would also try reinstalling that from scratch too.  If the problem persists, try another mouse for troubleshooting purposes and let me know how it works.

Comment: How old is the mouse? Is there maybe a broken or frayed cable?

Comment: To further @Mokubai's comment: try a different wired mouse before you go any further down the rabbit hole. The wire is the most common mode of failure. Buy a 10$ one or borrow a known-good one if you need to.

Comment: The corded mouse was actually the 3rd one I tried.  Initially, I was using a Microsoft Designer Mouse (Bluetooth) and I had assumed the lag was related to the Bluetooth adapter and possibly some power saving feature (which I turned off), next I tried a corded Kingston Trackball (which I already had, which I thought might just be too old), the Razor Mamba is newer than this computer (which is less than a month old).  I'll try the Razor drivers next, but I appreciate all of these ideas :)

Comment: I just calibrated a mouse pad. what an age we live in

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have an explanation as to why the two previous mice failed, however, the last 2 steps I completed that seemed to eliminate the issue are to install the Razer Synapsys software (which includes specialized drivers instead of the default Microsoft USB drivers) and to calibrate the mouse pad.  After using the computer for the last hour I am not getting the random mouse hanging, and I didn't need to resort to plugging in a modern mouse in a modern computer over an old PS/2 port.  Hope this helps others.